# Best way forward for setting up Debian 9 / MariaDB (10.1.26-0+deb9u1) with root user Adminer access

Tags: mariadb, authentication, debian

I have a new Debian 9 LAMP server (includes MariaDB v10.1.26 rather than MySQL). I note that in this build, the `debian-sys-maint` user no longer exists. Instead a unix_socket is used to grant root user access (so no password is required when logged in as MySQL root user, from the Linux root user account).

All in all, that seems like a great idea. However, I note that I can no longer log in to the root account via [Adminer](https://www.adminer.org/) (DB Admin web UI -somewhat like PHPMyAdmin).

So I disable the unix_socket and set a root password. Great, I can now log into the root account in Adminer. See the [MariaDB doc page](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/) for info.

However, as stated at the bottom of that doc: "Note that this may break scripts used by your OS distribution." and they give the workaround as writing the password to a config file. Obviously that would work, it's how the old `debian-sys-maint` user worked after all. But it seems a little backward to disable this new feature and revert to previous behaviour.

My question is then, should I instead create a new user with root level permissions for use in Adminer instead of allowing root password login? Or should I just recreate the `debian-sys-maint` user style set up?

Additionally, I have read about the [`mysql_config_editor`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-config-editor.html) tool which saves the passwords in some encrypted format, thus making the storage of the relevant password more secure. I note that that tool explicitly comes from MySQL (not MariaDB) and is not shipped with the default MariaDB server in Debian. If reverting to the old `debian-sys-maint` user style is the way to go, is there any recommendation on using (or trying to use) this tool with MariaDB? Or do I have to just lock down the permissions on the config file (e.g. 600)?